# rpy2 How to assign R dataframe to value/values

Tags: rpy2

If I have a python dataframe converted to r dataframe with:

Setup

```
import rpy2.robjects as ro
from rpy2.robjects.vectors import ListVector, DataFrame
from rpy2.robjects import numpy2ri, pandas2ri
from rpy2.robjects.conversion import localconverter
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
base = importr("base")
### do not activate rpy2.robjects.numpy2ri.activate() or pandas2ri
```

base looks like

> base
>
> rpy2.robjects.packages.Package as a <module 'base'>

```
with localconverter(ro.default_converter + pandas2ri.converter):
   r_df = ro.conversion.py2rpy(df)
```

How do I update the column to a new data type?
In python I would do:

```
r_['col1'] = 'test'
```

Or with r I would think it would be like:

```
r_df.rx2('col1') = base.as_Date(r_df.rx2('col1'), '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Versions:

pandas==1.0.1

rpy2~=3.3.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve what you want is:

```
r_df[r_df.colnames.index('col1')] = base.as_Date(r_df.rx2('col1'), '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Why is something like `r_df['col1']` not implemented? Because R can be peculiar, and a lot of choices in `rpy2` prefer a slight annoyance to a source of very hard-to-debug issues. Here this is because column names in an R data frame are not enforced to be unique, and getting an item by name will return the first one with that name. For example:

```
import rpy2.robjects as ro
dataf = ro.r('data.frame(x=1:3, x=4:6, check.names=FALSE)')

print(dataf)
#   x x
# 1 1 4
# 2 2 5
# 3 3 6

dataf.rx2('x')                                                          
# R object with classes: ('RTYPES.INTSXP',) mapped to:
# [1, 2, 3]
```

The Python method `index` is present in Python `list`, `tuple`, etc... and is documented to return the first matching index.

Comment: This produces: `AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'index'.` The converted python to R dataframe is not producing the same dataframe you have here with inline data.frame creation. It appears when using the converter that the "R dataframe" is a `R object with classes: ('data.frame',) mapped to: [IntSexpVe..., IntSexpVe..., StrSexpVe..., ...]
` but each column is also showing `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>` such as `event_time: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>   array(['2019-10-11', '2020-01-01', '2019-11-15', '2020-03-05'... `

Comment: For a follow up assuming that nump.ndarray is how the convertor is supposed to work then changing your code to: `r_df[np.where(r_df.colnames == 'col1'] = base.as_Date(r_df.rx2('col1'), '%Y-%m-%d')`. Produces `TypeError: 'module' object is not callable`

Comment: The result of your call `ro.conversion.py2rpy(df)` depends on the conversion rules set. If a `localconverter(ro.default_converter + pandas2ri.converter)`, and `df` is a `pandas.DataFrame` it will be an `rpy2.robjects.vectors.DataFrame`. You can verify this with `type(r_df)`.

Comment: The answer is otherwise calling `r_df.colnames.index('col1')` under default conversion rules (that is outside of the scope of the `localconverter` context manager block. If doing the same under `numpy` or `pandas` conversion rules it will not work because `r_df.colnames` will be converter to a `numpy` array (which does not implement the method `index` like other Python sequences do).

Comment: The documentation about the conversion system will provide more details about how it is working: https://rpy2.github.io/doc/v3.3.x/html/robjects_convert.html#conversion